# Image not downloading on android 2.3.3 and above android version

Tags: android, imagedownload

I have trouble with download image from server in my android app. If i try to download image from https://www.morroccomethod.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/category/resized/Trial_Sizes_4e4ac3b0d3491_175x175.jpg

My Code -

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url)
                .getContent());
```

It return null means image not downloading on 4.0.3 but image downloading successfully on 2.2
I think there may be problem with os version.

Now i want anyone to help and guide me for the same.

Comment: Check your InputStream returning null here with Android 4.0.3 or not and why it is not returning null in android 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below code into your activity.java file's onCreate method after setcontentview().

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Comment: @NandlalVirani yesterday i was solve my problem using this code.

Comment: Can you try this image URL in your code https://www.morroccomethod.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/category/resized/Trial_Sizes_4e4ac3b0d3491_175x175.jpg ?

Comment: Is it working on all version of android 2.2 , 2.3.3 , 4.0.3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Between 2.2 and 4.0.0 there were some changes regarding what you could do on the UI thread.

From your code snipit I can not tell what thread you are doing this on, but I would expect that this is the same problem.

Try loading your image using an AsyncTask, as you can not perform this http action on the UI thread.

Comment: I already did it using an AsyncTask.I am able to download same image from https://www.morroccomethod.com/mm/12.jpg but not from https://www.morroccomethod.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/category/resized/Trial_Sizes_4e4ac3b0d3491_175x175.jpg. I think there filename problem with different android versions.

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm about Network on UI Thread Exception and make sure that you are using AsyncTask. Try the same code with AsyncTask, this will help you.

Comment: I already did it using an AsyncTask.I am able to download same image from https://www.morroccomethod.com/mm/12.jpg but not from https://www.morroccomethod.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/category/resized/Trial_Sizes_4e4ac3b0d3491_175x175.jpg. I think there filename problem with different android versions

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
try
        {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(grabImageFromUrl(imageUrl));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("CATCH", "ImageDrawable");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and method code is::

```
private Drawable grabImageFromUrl(String imageUrlInput) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, Exception
    {
        return Drawable.createFromStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrlInput).getContent(), "src");
    }
```

I have created this code for you, try it worked at my end...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class image extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage("https://www.morroccomethod.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/category/resized/Trial_Sizes_4e4ac3b0d3491_175x175.jpg");
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;
    }

    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your code , I am able to download same image from morroccomethod.com/mm/12.jpg but not from https://www.morroccomethod.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/category/resized/Trial_Sizes_4e4ac3b0d3491_175x175.jpg. I think there filename problem .

Comment: If the **url** is showing the image in browser than it is able to be downloaded but you still talk to its owner or developer, mite having issue with the name.

Comment: owner cant change file name on server because it also reference other website.So is it possible in android to do some operation on URL like encoding/decoding to download it without changing name of file on server ?